# ValueError Issue with implementation of plotting uniform distribution

Tags: python, statistics, scipy.stats

so i am trying to plot a uniform distribution using scipy.stats, but am running into this error, to do with shape transformation, could someone please tell me why this is happening / how my code should look, thank you.

Full Code and traceback below:

```
# UNIFORM DISTRIBUTION:

from scipy.stats import uniform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

n = 10  # total data number

x = list(range(0, n + 1))

# create a list of values that follow uniform distribution
r = uniform.rvs(size=1000)
ax.vlines(x, 0, r, colors = "blue")
plt.show()
```

FULL TRACEBACK:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
> 12 # create a list of values that follow uniform distribution
> 13 r = uniform.rvs(size=1000)
> ---> 14 ax.vlines(x, 0, r, colors = "blue")
> 15 plt.show()
> 16

> \matplotlib_*init*_.py
> in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)    1436     def inner(ax, *args,
> data=None, **kwargs):    1437         if data is None:
> -> 1438             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)    1439     1440         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>
> \matplotlib\axes_axes.py
> in vlines(self, x, ymin, ymax, colors, linestyles, label, **kwargs)
> 1257         masked_verts[:, 0, 1] = ymin    1258
> masked_verts[:, 1, 0] = x
> -> 1259         masked_verts[:, 1, 1] = ymax    1260     1261         lines = mcoll.LineCollection(masked_verts, colors=colors,
>
> \numpy\ma\core.py
> in **setitem**(self, indx, value)    3378         if _mask is nomask:
> 3379             # Set the data, then the mask
> -> 3380             _data[indx] = dval    3381             if mval is not nomask:    3382                 _mask = self._mask =
> make_mask_none(self.shape, _dtype)
>
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1000) into
> shape (11)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to plot `x` with size `n=10` and `r` with size `size=1000`. They have to be the same size.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000
x = range(n)
# define the distribution
# by default [0,1]
# https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html
dist = sps.uniform()
# generate n random variates
r = dist.rvs(n)

plt.plot(x, r)
```

[image]